# Как реализовать алгоритм заливки в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть заготовка игры.

[image: скрин сцены]

Игрок(G), во время движения(красная стрелка), менял белые объекты(А) на зелёные (Еr).
Как заполнить внутреннюю площадь(или заменить белые объекты(A) на зеленые(Er))?

Я читал про [flood fill](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), но не разобрался, как его использовать.

Я так понимаю:

1. Создать очередь из объектов по которым прошел(в моем случае (А))
2. Для каждого объекта в очереди
3. Проверить объект находящийся на запад от него(если ты двигался  по оси -X ) по пути игрока и точно так же проверить объекты на восток(если  ты двигался  по оси X).
4. Если объект(А) изменить на (Er) и добавить в очередь и перейти к пункту 2. И или если объект (Er)то перейти к пункту 2.

---

Я правильно думаю? Может как то можно легче сделать? Подскажите  как правильно.

Comment: Давайте ещё раз. У вас есть поле из белых клеточек. Вы хотите, чтобы те, через которые прошёл игрок становились зелёными?

Comment: Интересует как залить прямоугольник в левом верхнем углу(который состоит из белых карточек) .Мой игрок двигается и создает края( в нашем случае прямоугольника из зеленых карточек)  а алгоритм должен заливать середину .